# How to get specific mobile device model on webapps using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the model name of mobile device like iphone **7**, iphone **8** or iphone **12** when my web app runs on mobile but I only get **iphone** and not the specific device model. I m currently using **react-device-detect**.

Is there any way to achieve this? I don't want to use any paid service.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

***code:***

```js
    import {deviceDetect,mobileModel} from "react-device-detect"

    ....

    useEffect(() => {
     console.log("devicedata deviceDetect", deviceDetect()) // gives object shown in image below
     console.log("devicedata browserName", mobileModel) // gives "iphone"
    },[])
```

**output:**
[image: ImageOutput]

Comment: i think useragent doesn't return the iphone version for example iphone5 or 13 etc.

Comment: so is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the user agent api data and do some regular expression to extract the useful information

```
const userAgent= navigator.userAgent
const device = {
  iPad: /iPad/.test(userAgent),
  iPhone: /iPhone/.test(userAgent),
  Android5: /Android 5/.test(uauserAgent,
 Android4: /Android 4/.test(uauserAgent
}
```

Read more about detecting information
[Detect Device - Broswer](https://medium.com/creative-technology-concepts-code/detect-device-browser-and-version-using-javascript-8b511906745)

[MDN User Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: thanks for answering but this still doesn't helps me to get the device model

Comment: This is tricky using the browser, I'm not sure about getting it, but if you use `Capacitor.js` I believe will give you the information you need, but I didn't try it yet on web to get mobile device info, so give it a try

[Capacitor.js-device](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/device)

Comment: ok thanks will give it a try